# How to change UIBezierPath background color?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have added these lines of code:

```
    var radius: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60
    let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height), cornerRadius: 0)

    let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 30, y: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - radius) / 2 - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, width: radius, height: radius), cornerRadius: radius)

    path.appendPath(circlePath)
```

but it gives me this result

[image]

How can I make my circle background color - clearColor() ?

I tried this one:

```
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
circlePath.fill()
```

But it did not make any sense

Comment: Why does it not make any sense ?

Comment: @A-Live that's that I want to know :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
let radius: CGFloat = 50
let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50), cornerRadius: 0)

let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius, height: radius), cornerRadius: radius)

path.append(circlePath)

let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
yourView.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

Paths do not have color; layers have color.

You need to create a layer based on a path, and add it to the layer of your view as shown in the code above.

Comment: @Marin Enjoy swifty coding.!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor);
```

Comment: Call circlePath.fill()  at last

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your advice. My English is not very good, but I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful that `CAShapeLayer` has a property called `fillColor` which by default is black.

If you want it to be clear just make it nil.

```
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()

    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: .init(x: .zero, y: bounds.height))
    linePath.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
    linePath.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: .zero))

    layer.path = linePath.cgPath
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.grey.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = nil // here
    layer.lineWidth = 1
```

[image]